# minification did not generate minified version

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms, bundling-and-minification

I am creating an asp.net webforms application and trying to minify my js+css files. I am using these guidelines: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/08/14/adding-bundling-and-minification-to-web-forms.aspx.

My webapplication was targeting .net 4.0 but I changed this to .net 4.5. When I look at the chrome developertoolssection in the sources tab and i look under bundles it does not look like it has been generated:

```
jquery?v=
```

I added the BundleConfig class:

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include("~/jscripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
    }
}
```

In the jscripts folder i got my js files amongst them: jquery-1.8.0.min.js
In the masterpage of the homepage I have:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server">
   <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") %>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

In the masterpage behindcode  OnInit-event I have :

```
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

When I debug the application it hits the renderstatement. Is it maybe that I need to register the bundles in a different class?

Comment: Not sure if this is the case when used in web forms, but in MVC if you are debugging (or more the point compiling in debug mode) the bundler will return the non-minified version, try switching to release mode and running again

Comment: Do you have both minified and full versions of the script available in your jscripts directory?

Comment: Is your issue now resolved?

Answer (score 5):

To be able to see the minified version in debug mode you can:

1. Set   BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;  in your bundleconfig.cs file
2. Set  compilation debug="false" in your web.config file